# Is there software I can use to draw this graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, math-software

So, I have this particular graph to consider. It has the vertex set $\{1,...,17\}$ and edge set $\{(i,j)|i+j ~\mbox{is prime}\}$. Define a cost function $c:E(G)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by setting $c((i,j))=i+j$. Apply Kruskal's algorithm to find a minimum cost spanning  tree of $G$. Now, I know how to do this but drawing the graph by hand and connecting vertices is rather tedious. In fact, it's pretty much impossible for me because of the large number of vertices. Is there any software I can draw this graph to be able to see things more clearly? If anyone has suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in Maple by the short code

```
with(GraphTheory):
M := Matrix(17, 17, (i, j) -> if is(i+j, prime) and i+j <> 2 
then i+j else 0 end if):
G := Graph(M);
KruskalsAlgorithm(G, w, animate);
```

See one of the frames:
[image]

The loop at vertex $1$ ($1+1=2$) should be excluded from $G$.
See that animation in action [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/neqxc9est95kl0q/KruskalsAlgorithm.mw?dl=0).

Comment: Also see [GraphTheory](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GraphTheory) for info.

Comment: Please note that code is formatted by a block with all lines starting with four spaces. Using $\LaTeX$ for code makes it really ugly. I've edited your answer to fix this. In fact, you can turn your text into code by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl+K` or clicking `{}` button in the formatting toolbar of the editor.

Comment: @ Ruslan : Many thanks from me to you.